# view partitions in Linux using python3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

recently I just started to use python3 and realised that there alot of changes made from python2.6. I want to know is there anyway to format the view of the hard disks available in a linux system by using fdisk? in python2.6, it worked something like this;

```
def parse_fdisk(fdisk_output):
    result = {}
    for line in fdisk_output.split("\n"):
        if not line.startswith("/"): continue
        parts = line.split()

        inf = {}
        if parts[1] == "*":
            inf['bootable'] = True
            del parts[1]

        else:
            inf['bootable'] = False

        inf['start'] = int(parts[1])
        inf['end'] = int(parts[2])
        inf['blocks'] = int(parts[3].rstrip("+"))
        inf['partition_id'] = int(parts[4], 16)
        inf['partition_id_string'] = " ".join(parts[5:])

        result[parts[0]] = inf
    return result

def main():
    fdisk_output = commands.getoutput("fdisk -l")
    for disk, info in parse_fdisk(fdisk_output).items():
        print disk, " ".join(["%s=%r" % i for i in info.items()])
```

Comment: An actual description of your problem would have been useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `commands` module has been removed from Python3. You can use the `subprocess` module instead:

```
import subprocess
import shlex
import sys

def parse_fdisk(fdisk_output):
    result = {}
    for line in fdisk_output.split("\n"):
        if not line.startswith("/"): continue
        parts = line.split()

        inf = {}
        if parts[1] == "*":
            inf['bootable'] = True
            del parts[1]

        else:
            inf['bootable'] = False

        inf['start'] = int(parts[1])
        inf['end'] = int(parts[2])
        inf['blocks'] = int(parts[3].rstrip("+"))
        inf['partition_id'] = int(parts[4], 16)
        inf['partition_id_string'] = " ".join(parts[5:])

        result[parts[0]] = inf
    return result

def main():
    proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("fdisk -l"),
                            stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    fdisk_output, fdisk_error = proc.communicate()
    fdisk_output = fdisk_output.decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
    for disk, info in parse_fdisk(fdisk_output).items():
        print(disk, " ".join(["%s=%r" % i for i in info.items()]))

main()
```

No change was made to the `parse_fdisk` function. 
The only thing that needed changing was the call to `commands.getoutput` in `main()`.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) package.

> psutil is a module providing an interface for retrieving information on all running processes and system utilization (CPU, disk, memory) in a portable way by using Python, implementing many functionalities offered by command line tools such as: ps, top, df, kill, free, lsof, netstat, ifconfig, nice, ionice, iostat, iotop, uptime, tty.

From their [README](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/source/browse/trunk/README#19):

> It currently supports **Linux**, **Windows**, **OSX** and **FreeBSD** both
>   **32-bit** and  **64-bit** with Python versions from **2.4** to **3.3** by using
>   a single code base.

Disk example:

```
>>> psutil.disk_partitions()
[partition(device='/dev/sda1', mountpoint='/', fstype='ext4'),
 partition(device='/dev/sda2', mountpoint='/home', fstype='ext4')]
>>>
>>> psutil.disk_usage('/')
usage(total=21378641920, used=4809781248, free=15482871808, percent=22.5)
>>>
>>> psutil.disk_io_counters()
iostat(read_count=719566, write_count=1082197, read_bytes=18626220032, 
       write_bytes=24081764352, read_time=5023392, write_time=63199568)
```

Partition details (e.g. bootable flag) aren't supported (yet), as far as I can tell.

Comment: this is a very nice module to have. however, is there anyway i can grab out the partition details? I need to see the partition id of the hard disk aside from the hard disk name.