# how to display linux partitions using python?

Tags: python, linux

I am trying to display partitions of linux using python and i want to do it using APIs. I have just tried the following code to get the output.

```
import os

f = os.popen ("df -h")
for i in f.readlines():
print "myresult : ", i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df command used for - report file system disk space usage

I think you required fdisk for Partition table manipulator for Linux.

you can use either os.popen or subprocess. just need root user login before running python script.

Comment: yeah..that is the problem...i'm not allowed to be the root user :(..so cannot use fdisk

Comment: yes for that, you need to run python script using sudo command. 
read accepted answer in this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869574/view-partitions-in-linux-using-python3-x

Comment: thanks for d link..i tried the code.. it is not giving any error..but it isn't giving any output either..

Comment: Because it's required access permission, that you may not applied.

copy that same code in py file. then run that same file using this command.
1) cd <to script location>
2) sudo python <your python script name>

Comment: one more question..is there any way to display d partitions without being root or using sudo command?? is there any API in python which can do so??

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but on linux, `/proc/partitions` is a special file that lists the partitions, but you probably want  `/proc/mounts`

Answer (score 0):

The folder `/dev` contains various devices. From these, devices named like `sd[a-z]n` (`/dev/sda1`, for instance) (on old machines with IDE drives `hd[a-z]n)`, (where n-integer) are partitions. You can list using the file system access.

This has some limitations like unusual formatting of the whole drive as partition, but in general should work and also detect non-Linux partitions and with some luck USB sticks.